# Magento 2 : UTM params are not passed in the checkout/cart URL In Abandoned Cart Email button

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, google-analytics, abandoned-cart

I am using the `Magento 2.3.6` instance for my live website. I've used Mirasvit's [Follow Up Email for Magento 2](https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/follow-up-email.html) extension to send Abandoned cart emails to my customers.

My store sends Abandoned cart emails to customers as per the configuration set in admin.

The customers receive the email with the proper URL as below:
[image]

But when click on the `Complete Checkout` button it takes me to the https://my-site.com/checkout/cart/ page and removes the UTM params from the URL.
So I am unable to track the Abandoned Cart email in my Google Analytics.

I want that the checkout/cart URL should have UTMs params as below mentioned Expected URL:

**Abandoned cart email URL:**

> https://my-site.com/emailreport/track/click/qid/336a3bb9ef2fd12b1276b6f245cb144d88487068efb69eb022242240a5da551e/?url=aHR0cHM6Ly9qYWRlYmx1ZS5jb20vZW1haWwvYWN0aW9uL3Jlc3RvcmVDYXJ0P2hhc2g9MzM2YTNiYjllZjJmZDEyYjEyNzZiNmYyNDVjYjE0NGQ4ODQ4NzA2OGVmYjY5ZWIwMjIyNDIyNDBhNWRhNTUxZQ%3D%3D&utm_source=follow-up-email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=abandoned%20shopping%20cart

**Actual URL:**

> https://my-site.com/checkout/cart/

**Expected URL:**

> https://my-site.com/checkout/cart/?utm_campaign=abandoned+shopping+cart&utm_medium=email&utm_source=follow-up-email

Can anyone please suggest here how I pass the UTM parameters in my checkout page URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for my issue. After debugging the problem I got to know that the server removes the UTM marks if they are connected with the URL via `?` like this: `?utm_source=follow-up-email&utm_medium..`

But if I use `#` to connect the URL with the UTM marks I can see these UTM marks are added correctly to the page: https://prnt.sc/LW7O4lONXFpU
[image]

To do this, I added UTM marks directly to the abandoned cart template: https://prnt.sc/M0Qy-RJK67k1
[image]

I hope this may help someone!